# How to configure McAfee to allow network share access?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

Someone at an office decided to install McAfee on to one of their computers.

After doing this, that machine could not be pinged from any other machine and its network shares were no longer accessible which caused some of their networked software to stop working.

I asked them to uninstall McAfee and then everything to returned to normal.  Now they want me to sort it out so that McAfee can be on that machine and have everything work.

What do I need to do to the configuration of McAfee so that is allows access to the machine's network shares?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe can help you;

Step 1: With the left mouse button, double-click on the 'McAfee SecurityCenter' icon in the System Tray area.

Step 2: With the left mouse button, click on 'personal firewall plus.

Step 3: With the left mouse button, click on 'Options'.

Step 4: With the left mouse button, click on 'Trusted & Banned IPs' below 'Tools'.

Step 5: With the left mouse button, click on the 'Banned IP Addresses' tab.

Step 6: If any of your computers are listed here, remove them from the list.

Step 7: With the left mouse button, click on the 'Trusted IP Addresses' tab.

Step 8: With the left mouse button, click on the 'Add' button.

Step 9: Enter a Single IP Address in the 'IP Address' text box or an IP Address Range in the 'From IP Address' and the 'To IP Address' text boxes.

Step 10: Enter a descriptive name in the 'Description' text box.

Step 11: With the left mouse button, click on the 'OK' button.

Step 12: With the left mouse button, click on the 'OK' button.

Step 13: With the left mouse button, click on the 'Close' button  to close the McAfee personal firewall plus

Step 14: With the left mouse button, click on the 'Close' button  to close the McAfee SecurityCenter.

Step 15: Access your shared folders / files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Regarding steps 4-9, can computer names be used instead of IP addresses?

Comment: Yeah .. Welcome, I think it can't .